# Why was Doc Brown surprised at how Marty was dressed upon arriving in 1885?

Tags: time-travel, back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-iii

I mean, he chose the clothes, albeit 30 years prior from his perspective, it doesn't seem that forgettable.

Comment: Because of how ridiculous it was compared to how everyone else dressed at the time.  Marty was dressed like Howdy Doody, rather than Wyatt Earp

Comment: @CBredlow - I think he's asking about the lapse in Doc's memory rather than how ridiculous Marty looks.